# Given a svn branch / revision, can GitHub tell me the sha?

Tags: git, svn, github

One of my "legacy" system checks out code from GitHub using svn (e.g. svn co https://github.com/user/repo/trunk).

Is there a GitHub API (or command) I can use to map the svn branch / revision back to the Git sha?

I'm aware of git-svn and find-rev, but as far as I can tell, you first do 'git svn clone ...'  and then 'git svn find-rev ...'. I don't want to checkout the whole repo just to look up the revision.

Comment: http://schacon.github.io/git/git-ls-remote.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here,

https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients#other-tricks

In summary, you can do this,

```
$ svn propget git-commit --revprop -r 1000 https://github.com/rails/rails/trunk
480150e5fb73f1a6a23bb08fdf9a537ccbd6f60d
```

Answer (score 0):

As zerkms already commented, you can use 'git ls-remote' for that:

```
git ls-remote <remote>
```

That will list you all branches of the specified remote. You can give the command a configured remote (e.g. `origin`) if you call while being in a git repo, or you can just give it an uri to the remote (e.g. 'ssh://user@host:port/path/to/repo').

If you only want a specific branch (or tag), you can give it additional arguments:

```
git ls-remote <remote> master
```

That give you the sha of the remote branch 'master' only.

Also, check the manual of `git ls-remote` for more info:

```
man git-ls-remote
```